# How can I define the sequence of properties in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have following java Object:

**ProcessBean.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRootName;

@JsonRootName(value = "process")
public class ProcessBean{
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String user;
    private String executePermissions;
    private String createdDtm;
    private String updatedDtm;
    private Process tpProcess;
    private List<ProcessParamBean> processParameters;

    /* --------Getters and Setters ----------*/
}
```

I need to find the JSON schema for this object which is used to display these fields on UI. The order of fields in UI is determined by the order of properties in JSON schema generated.

I have generated the schema using following code:

**DataSpec.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchema;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.factories.SchemaFactoryWrapper;

public class DataSpec {
    public static <T> String getDataSpec(Class<T> clazz) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
        MetauiVisitorContext obj = new MetauiVisitorContext();
        visitor.setVisitorContext(obj);
        try {
            mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(clazz, visitor);
            JsonSchema schema = visitor.finalSchema();
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(schema);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**MetauiVisitorContext.java**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.factories.VisitorContext;

public class MetauiVisitorContext extends VisitorContext{
    @Override
    public String getSeenSchemaUri(JavaType aSeenSchema) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The resultant schema looks like below:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:restservices:api:jsonbeans:ProcessBean",
  "properties": {
    "updatedDtm": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "createdDtm": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "tpProcess": {
      "type": "object",
      "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:restservices:api:jsonbeans:Process",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "processParameters": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:restservices:api:jsonbeans:ProcessParamBean",
        "properties": {
          "updatedDtm": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "defaultValue": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "createdDtm": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "masterParam": {
            "type": "object",
            "id": "urn:jsonschema:com:restservices:api:jsonbeans:MasterParamBean",
            "properties": {
              "updatedDtm": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "createdDtm": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "description": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "processParamId": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "id": {
             "type": "integer"
          },
          "userPrompted": {
             "type": "boolean"
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "executePermissions": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

As it can be seen that the order of properties in JSON schema does not match the order of fields defined in Java object which is necessary in my case.

So how can I determine the sequence of the properties?

Answer (score 10):

There is not an intrinsic order of properties in a JSON schema object, as it happens with a regular JSON or javascript object. Indeed, it does not change the validation semantics. The following schemas validate exactly the same collection of objects:

Schema 1:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "prop1" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "prop2" : {
            "type" : "number"
        }
    }
}
```

Schema 2:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "prop2" : {
            "type" : "number"
        },
        "prop1" : {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to preserve some ordering you need to do it within and array. You could achieve this by using an array of objects instead of an object in the items clause. An example:

```
{
    "type" : "array",
    "items" : [{
            "properties" : {
                "prop2" : {
                    "type" : "number"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "properties" : {
                "prop1" : {
                    "type" : "string"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This way you get an ordered definition of UI items. Unfortunately, it forces you to nest each single property in an object.

Answer (score 5):

Order is out of scope for json-schema. For that you need to look into **json-forms** https://jsonforms.io/, standards, which is extension of json-schema. It consist of three separate JSON data :

1. schema
2. values
3. ui-schema

The ui-schema contains the information about the ui and presentation, like order of properties (fields) and the their visual presentation, like "hidden", "read-only".